# Display pdf in a new tab with custom filename

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, angular-httpclient, window.open

I am reading a pdf in the server (SpringBoot) and return it as a byte array to be opened in a new tab. On the client-side (Angular) I am consuming it as a blob. I am then trying to open the pdf in a new tab

**service.ts** file

```
getPdf(httpHeaders: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getServerUrl() + 'dummypdf', {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob',
        headers: httpHeaders
    });
}
```

**Component.ts** file

```
openPdf(){
    this.service.getPdf(generateRequestId()).subscribe(file => {
        let blobData = new Blob([file.body], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        let fileData = new File([file.body], "name", {type: 'application/pdf'});
        let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileData);
        window.open(fileURL,"_blank")
    })
}
```

I am able to open the pdf in the new tab. Everything is fine. But the blob URL appears as such

```
blob:http://localhost:4200/ba35a67c-571e-4450-bda4-b438dc8d6d8e
```

I do understand that it is because of the memory location from where it is reading and also it is not customizable.

**My question is, Is there any alternative approach to this. Like perhaps not consume it as a blob or not sending it as a byte array from the server?**

Comment: Can you give a try downloading and then opening the same file..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But then in a use case where a user would like to view multiple pdfs to just view, it will unnecessary download the files.

Comment: Is it necessary to show pdf in different tab? Can you try with be in same tab's some popup view

Comment: Instead of streaming the file as a blob, can you try creating and saving file server side in a MEDIA/STATIC location and save that path in your database to open it as a PDF on the client side as a static file.

Comment: @Romesh No. An iframe is one option perhaps, but recent browsers block the iframes.

Comment: @Sunny - Not sure. Need to check if it is possible. I was thinking something more on client-side